# Vue computed undefined

Tags: vue.js

In my component I have:

```
    mounted () {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadTickets')
    },
    computed: {
            ticketLast() {
            return this.$store.state.tickets.slice(-1)[0];
            },
             ...mapState([
            'tickets'
            ]),
    }
```

store:

```
 state: {
      tickets: []
    }
    actions: {
      loadTickets ({ commit }) {
        axios
        .get('/tickets.json')
        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(tickets => {
         commit('SET_TICKETS', tickets);
         })
       },
    },
    mutations: {
      SET_TICKETS (state, tickets) {
      state.tickets = tickets
      },
    }
```

In template

```
<div class="form-info-grid">
   <div class="form-info">
     {{ ticketLast.number }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-info">
      {{ ticketLast.date | formatDate }}
    </div>
  </div>
```

shows the correct value, but in console I get:

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'number' of
>   undefined"

Any idea about why this is happening?

Comment: Show how you are trying to print it.  Please provide an [mre]

Comment: I would guess that you initially set `tickets` to an empty array and when that tries to render it fails as entry `[0]` will be `undefined`. When the real array subsequently loads from the server it will trigger a re-render, this time without an error and showing the correct value. Try putting in some console logging or a `debugger` statement so you can see what `ticketLast` returns.

Comment: Yes ido set initially tickets as an empty array, but it gets filled on mounted before the renders isn't it?

Comment: You cannot know whether the store gets filled before `mounted()` - `loadtickets()` is an async function that returns a value when the data arrives from the API. If you didn't see this error, then it would be pure luck. Try returning a value (even an empty one) in your computed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet below solves the problem - but do you see the flicker of the displayed data? (Sometimes) That is the **async** function - you don't have `tickets.slice(-1)[0]`, as for a time the ticket array is empty - and an empty array doesn't have a last element, and therefore this "last element" cannot have a **number** property.

(I had to edit your example code some to get it to work with mockup JSON.)

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    tickets: []
  },
  actions: {
    loadTickets({
      commit
    }) {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(tickets => {
          commit('SET_TICKETS', tickets)
        })
      /*axios
        .get('/tickets.json')
        .then(r => r.data)
        .then(tickets => {
          commit('SET_TICKETS', tickets);
        })*/
    },
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_TICKETS(state, tickets) {
      state.tickets = tickets
      console.log(state.tickets)
    },
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadTickets')
  },
  computed: {
    ticketLast() {
      return this.$store.state.tickets.slice(-1)[0] || {
        id: '',
        title: Date.now()
      };
    },
    /*...mapState([
      'tickets'
    ]),*/
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.1/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="form-info-grid">
    <div class="form-info">
      {{ ticketLast.id }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-info">
      {{ ticketLast.title}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep this way the error goes away. Using a static id, when it renders it shows for a little while the ticket corresponding to the static id and then changes to then actual latest one. Thanks!